# How to deduplicate a string where it only deletes consecutive duplicates

Tags: c++

The goal of the program is to take a string like "kcck" and delete the consecutive duplicates. It should first iterate through the string and delete `cc` leaving `kk`; then go through again and delete `kk`; then return "empty" since there are no characters left in the string.

Another example, "aabggtcc" should return "bt".

```
int i;
int j = i+1;

string deduplicate(string input) {

    for(i=0; i<input.length(); ++i) {

       while(j <input.length()) {

           if(input[i] == input[j]) {
               input.erase(i);
               input.erase(j);
           }
           else if (input[i] != input[j]) {
               ++i; ++j;
           }
           if(input[i] == '\0') {
               cout<<"empty";
           }
       }
   }
   return 0;
}

int main () {

    cout<<deduplicate("aabg")<<endl;
    cout<<deduplicate("ag")<<endl;
    cout<<deduplicate("btaabb")<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code it gives me:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
```

Comment: `deduplicate` function expected to return `string`. Please check for compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your snippet,

1. `deduplicate` function is returning `zero(0)` all the time
2. `j` is initialized in global scope and is never reset for new `string`
3. As you erase `std::string::length()` is calculated on new string hence your index `i` and `j` are won't point to same laocation.

Here is the  snippet with rectified error,

```
string deduplicate(string input) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < input.length()) {
        j = i + 1;
        bool isRepeated = false;
        while (j < input.length()) {
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {
                input.erase(j,1);
                --j; //as string length is reduced by 1
                isRepeated = true;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        if (isRepeated) {
            input.erase(i,1); //remove first letter as well
            --i;//sting length is reduced by one
        }
        ++i;
    }

    return input;
}

int main() {

    std::cout << deduplicate("aabg") << endl;
    std::cout << deduplicate("ag") << endl;
    std::cout << deduplicate("btaabb") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
bg
ag
t
```

which can be even simplified as,

```
std::string deduplicate(std::string input) {
    std::string s ="";
    for (auto c : input) //loop through all char
    {
        int f = 0;
        for (auto c1 : input) 
        {
            if (c1 == c)
            {
                f++; //increment if char is found
            }
        }

        if (f == 1)//append char only if it present ones
            s += c;
    }   
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Im pretty baffled at how many ways there are to solve these problems. Ive spent days on this problem and it has made me feel painfully stupid. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are decreasing the size of the string whenever you call `string.erase()` that's why the variable `i` eventually exceeds the "current" string size `input.length()` in the `while` loop, and you get an error `std::out_of_range: basic_string` when you try to access `input[i]` in the `if` and `else if` conditions of the loop.

Try to manually go through the loop on the string on which you got the error and you will see that `i` has gone out of bound (i.e. `i >= input.length()`) in the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 and on, instead of iterating over each character and making the comparison manually, you can use [std::basic_string::find_first_not_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to look forward from a position in the string and find the first character not of the current character. If the position returned by `.find_first_not_of` is more than `1` from the current position, you can use `.erase` to erase that number characters. If the return is `1`, then just increment your current position and repeat.

To operate on all duplicates characters in the modified string, you simply wrap it all in an outer-loop, keep a copy of the string before before entering the inner-loop to remove duplicate characters, and compare if the modified string is equal to your copy or the `.length()` is zero for your exit condition.

You can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    std::string s;

    while (getline (std::cin, s)) {
        std::string current;
        do {
            size_t pos = 0;
            current = s;
            while (pos < s.length()) {
                size_t duplicates = s.find_first_not_of (s.at(pos), pos);
                if (duplicates != std::string::npos && duplicates > pos + 1)
                    s.erase(s.begin() + pos, s.begin() + duplicates);
                else if (duplicates == std::string::npos && 
                        (s.end() - s.begin() - pos) > 1)
                    s.erase(s.begin() + pos, s.end());
                else
                    pos++;
            }
        } while (current != s && s.length());
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'\n";
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "kcck" | ./bin/ddcpp
''

$ echo "aabggtcc" | ./bin/ddcpp
'bt'

$ echo "aabg" | ./bin/ddcpp
'bg'

$ echo "ag" | ./bin/ddcpp
'ag'

$ echo "btaabb" | ./bin/ddcpp
'bt'
```

There are a number of ways to approach the problem and as long as they are reasonably efficient there isn't any one right/wrong way. If you have a modern C++ compiler, letting some of the built-in container functions handle the work is generally a bit more robust than reinventing it on your own. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Always *more than one way to skin the cat* with C++.

Comment: Hmmm `"btaabb"` looks like you will get rid of `"aabb"` and then that doesn't leave anything else to chop. Is that the one you were referring to?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, all the `char` has to be removed if there exist more than one repetition. `"btaabb"` expected output would be `"t"`

Comment: I guess I don't then, because if you remove `"aa"` you have `"btbb"`,then you remove `"bb"` leaving `"bt"` which has no further ***"consecutive duplicates"***.